# How to handle the value I get from a HashMap

Tags: rust

I want my `getv()` function return the value from a `HashMap`. I get errors no matter how I modify my code:

```
enum Type {
    TyInt,
    TyBool,
}

struct TypeEnv {
    Env: HashMap<char, Type>,
}
impl TypeEnv {
    fn set(&mut self, name: char, ty: Type) {
        self.Env.insert(name, ty);
    }

    fn getv(self, name: char) -> Type {
        match self.Env.get(&name) {
            Some(Type) => Type, // <------- Always error here
            None => Type::TyInt,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "match arms have incompatible types" error.     If I modify this line to Some(Type) => *Type, then I get "cannot move out of borrowed content". How to make this work ? :(

Comment: Show the full compiler error, in your question. That helps.

Comment: Your `Type` is the enum name (or type), not its values, while `Type::TyInt` is a enum value. These are not the same type, as per the error message. It's perhaps similar to return a `f64` in one arm, and returning a `1.0` in another arm.

Comment: Try matching with `Some(x) => x,` instead. `x` should be of `Type`, and you'll want to return its value (as far as I understand your code).

Comment: In all likelihood (again, if I understand your code correctly), you should probably use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html): that'll return the value inside an option, or a default.

Comment: I tried this "Some(x) => x" but get error "match arms have incompatible types [E0308]:
expected type `main::Type`
   found type `&main::Type`
match arm with an incompatible type
expected enum `main::Type`, found &main::Type".   If I modify it to "Some(x) => *x" then I get error "cannot move out of borrowed content" :(

Comment: You can't move it, because it still belongs to the hashmap. That's why you see the second error.

Comment: **Please** read up on what idiomatic Rust code looks like. Variables should be `snake_case`, *not* `PascalCase`.

Answer (score 10):

`HashMap::get` returns an `Option<&Type>`, not an `Option<Type>`, which is why just returning the matched value fails to compile.

`get` provides a reference because in Rust you cannot simply return the actual value that is in the hash table - you need to either *clone* it (make a copy, potentially expensive), *remove* it from the container and transfer it to the caller, or return a *reference* to the value inside. `HashMap::get` chooses the last option because it is cheap while providing the greatest flexibility to the caller, which can choose to either inspect the value or clone it.

For your enum that consists of a single machine word, copying the value would be the optimal approach. (For more complex enums, a better approach is to return a reference as shown in [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47285228/1600898).) Copying requires:

- making `Type` copyable, by marking it with the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait using the `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` directive at the type definition.
- returning the copy from `getv` by dereferencing the matched value using `*matched_value`, or by using `&` in the pattern.

Finally, your `getv` method consumes the object, which means that you can call it only once. This is almost certainly not what was intended - it should accept `&self` instead. With those changes, the resulting code looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Type {
    TyInt,
    TyBool,
}

struct TypeEnv {
    env: HashMap<char, Type>,
}

impl TypeEnv {
    fn set(&mut self, name: char, ty: Type) {
        self.env.insert(name, ty);
    }

    fn getv(&self, name: char) -> Type {
        match self.env.get(&name) {
            Some(&v) => v,
            None => Type::TyInt,
        }
    }
}
```

If the type needs to contain non-`Copy` data, then you can make it only `Clone` instead, and return `v.clone()`.

Comment: Whilst possibly an oversight by the OP, you've not fixed the ownership issue with `TypeEnv`. The `getv` function takes ownership of `self` ... and therefore [you can't actually use this type in a useful way](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=e9e3223c80ef59a490f8979c290500e9&version=stable)... even though it compiles when you don't use it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Good point, I've now fixed `getv` to accept `&self`, which is almost certainly what the OP intended. Rust's type system is so good that it almost spoils us with "if it compiles, it's perfect" mindset.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to make your type `Copy` or `Clone` ... if you're happy working with the reference.

When things like this pop up while writing Rust, its generally best to re-evaluate how you're calling the code. Can it be made simpler?

You can either have the caller expect the `Option<&V>`, or just force *something* out... perhaps like this:

```
fn getv(&self, name: char) -> &Type {
    self.env.get(&name).unwrap_or(&Type::TyInt)
}
```

This simplifies your code and makes it pretty clear what you're after. [Here it is in action](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=ec52f29a1e3a78f5efa6d3f0332d8bf6&version=stable):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Type {
    TyInt,
    TyBool,
}

struct TypeEnv {
    env: HashMap<char, Type>,
}

impl TypeEnv {
    fn set(&mut self, name: char, ty: Type) {
        self.env.insert(name, ty);
    }

    fn getv(&self, name: char) -> &Type {
        self.env.get(&name).unwrap_or(&Type::TyInt)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut te = TypeEnv {
        env: HashMap::new(),
    };
    {
        let arg = te.getv('c');

        println!("{:?}", arg); // "TyInt" - because nothing was found
    }

    te.set('c', Type::TyBool);

    let arg = te.getv('c'); // "TyBool" - because we stored it in the line above.

    println!("{:?}", arg);
}
```

Also, your existing implementation of `getv` takes ownership of `self` ... notice how I added the reference `getv(&self)`. If you don't have this, this type (as far as I can tell) becomes [basically useless](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=e9e3223c80ef59a490f8979c290500e9&version=stable).

Comment: If `Type` is something as simple as a C-style enum, i.e. if it fits into a machine word, then it makes no sense to return it by reference, just like it rarely makes sense to return an `usize` by reference. Doing so is valid Rust, but it carries no performance benefits (and can in fact cause penalties), while negatively impacting ergonomics of the API.

Comment: A fair point you make @user4815162342. I figured offering an alternative still helps the OP. I generally work off the assumption that the example provided is much smaller in scope than what the actual problem is, since we do kind of expect an MCVE and sometimes people reach for small/fast copyable types.

Comment: Agreed - if `Type` is at all heavy, you'd want to avoid copying it. To clarify what I meant by "negatively impacting ergonomics", notice the unnatural block enclosing the first usage of `arg`. This is a consequence of `arg` being a shared reference to data inside `te` whose continued existence precludes creating a mutable reference to `te` required by `TypeEnv::set`.